# How do i loop audio in Voice channel in discord.js

Tags: javascript, loops, discord.js

Im trying to find a way to loop audio with out any interval.I want to repeat audio in voicechannel for forever

Comment: Depending on how you implement the audio playing, you might have an event fired when the audio stops playing.

Answer (score 0):

You Could use setInterval

```
setInterval(() => {
    //CODE
}, Numb of Sec Before Loop);
```